# Application of the residue theorem: how to use angular sectors

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am studying the residue theorem applications to physics and in particular the angular sector method. I understand the concept of finding an angle such that the infinite half-segment along it acts as the real axis, but I found an integral that I do not know how to solve with this method:

> $$\int{\frac{1-x}{1+x^3}}$$

I tried the following:

$$ \oint{\frac{1-z}{1-z^3} dz}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}dx} + \int_{\infty}^0{\frac{1-z}{1+z^3}dz}=2\pi i \Sigma_jRes(f, z_j)$$

And taking $z=re^{2\pi i/3}$ in the last integral, I get

$$ \oint{\frac{1-z}{1-z^3} dz}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}dx} - \int^{\infty}_0{\frac{1-re^{2 \pi i /3}}{1+r^3}dr}=2\pi i \Sigma_jRes(f, z_j)$$

What I wanted to get is something of the form $(1-a)I=2\pi i \Sigma_j Res(f,z_j)$, but I dont see anyway of factorizing. What should I do ?

By the way, the integral should vanish, maybe it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two parts:

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1-x}{1+x^3}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^3}dx
$$

This will make it easier to "have the factor come out". Use the contour:

[image: integration contour]

The last segment is $[R\omega, 0]$, where $\omega = \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$. Notice that $w^3 = 1$ so that will allow us to relate the integrals along the last segment with the integrals we want.

For $f_1(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^3}$ we get

$$
\int_{[R\omega,0]} f_1(z)dz = -\int_{[0,R\omega]} f_1(z)dz
= -\int_0^R \frac{1}{1+(\omega t)^3}\omega dt = -\omega \int_0^R \frac{1}{1+t^3} dt 
$$

Over the circle contour, as $R\to \infty$, the integral will vanish (basically because the denominator is of power that is at least $2$ bigger than the numerator). The contour encloses one pole $z_1 = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ of $f_1$, so by the residue theorem, we get

$$
(1-\omega)\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx = 2\pi i Res(f_1, z_1) = \frac{1}{3z_1^2}
$$

The integral for $f_2(z)=\frac{z}{1+z^3}$ goes similarly. But now on the segment $[R\omega, 0]$ as we plug in $\omega t$, another factor of $\omega$ comes out from the numerator. Here too the circular part vanishes in the limit. We have

$$
(1-\omega^2)\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^3}dx = 2\pi i Res(f_2, z_1) = \frac{z_1}{3z_1^2}
$$

So all in all we have

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1-x}{1+x^3}dx =
2\pi i \frac{1}{3(1-\omega)z_1^2} - 2\pi i \frac{z_1}{3(1-\omega^2)z_1^2}
= 2\pi i \frac{(1-\omega^2)-(1-\omega)z_1}{2(1-\omega)(1+\omega^2)z_1^2} = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer !